# AWS EC2 RHEL7 Instance permission problem

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have set all the folders in my /var/www/upload directory to 755. But still my php application hosted on that server is not performing file uploads. Please tell me how to fix this permission problem and how my php file uploading will be working fine. 
It does not shows any error. Just file is not moved to the intended folder.

Comment: Can you please try to upload a file in a manual way? if it's giving error then will make sure that you have permission problem otherwise your code is not working
Share the command what you have fired for changing the permission

Comment: Uploading file manually is not showing any error. And the same code is working on my local server

Comment: I used the command to change the permission :::: sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/www    and then sudo chmod 755 /var/www